# Can rubber hoods be used on a different brand of brake levers?

Tags: road-bike, brake-levers

The rubber hoods on my SRAM levers have started to tear. However, locally there are only a couple of Shimano rubber hoods.

Can they fit and what should I pay attention to?

Comment: I'd order a new set of hoods online if you can. If not, you're going to have to start trying repairs (maybe if you clean the area with rubbing alcohol and apply a bit of contact cement, it might seal the tear, but what works depends on the hood's materials and stuff), or some soft tape (e.g. adhesive bar tape) or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The rubber hoods are designed to closely match the lever's shape and are not stretched when installed. There are some third party replacement hoods, but they too are designed to fit specific lever models.

If you can't find the correct part locally, there are many mail order shops that have good selection of even uncommon or old spare parts.